# how to remove a particular callback from handler in jquery or javascript

Tags: jquery, events, callback, handler

Hi i want to remove the particular callback from the handler in jquery from body element. I am using the ajax calls to load the content in the page and the main page loads for one time and the sub pages includes the handlers for the body element. Each time the sub page loads it adds the callbacks to the body element. is there any solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use namespaced event names and then remove it like in `subpage 1` when the events are added to `body`

```
$('body').off('click.page1');
$('body').on('click.page1', function(){
})
```

Answer (score 0):

See jquery's [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) method. You should be able to do something like this:

```
var handler = function() {
  alert( "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog." );
};
$( "#foo" ).bind( "click", handler );
$( "#foo" ).unbind( "click", handler );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `off` before adding the handler using `on`.

```
$(document.body).off('the_event_name', theOldHandlerFunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myimage').click(function() { return false; }); // Adds another click event
$('#myimage').off('click');
$('#myimage').on('click.mynamespace', function() { /* Do Something*/ });
$('#myimage').off('click.mynamespace');
```

Using the **[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)/[off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)** functions